# align grid with different size pictures

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, masonry

[image]

I want a grid layout with images in the boxes like in the shown picture. I already tried bootstrap, but as the images have different sizes, I can't get them to fill boxes of the same size (let alone height) and always end up using too small boxes (e.g. col-md-4) with the images overlapping or too big boxes (like col-md-5) with too big margins between the images.

Do you guys think, masonry is a good solution, or is there one with bootstrap I don't think of?

Comment: Is the layout above static and you want you images to fit them, or it should be generated dynamically for a perfect rect contained grid based on the size (aspect ratio) of your images?

Comment: To questions like this, the answer always seems to be masonry. I was thinking masonry even before I'd read the question text!

Comment: it should be static :)
okay, I'll try myself on masonry :)